# Markers en google maps no se dibujan en chrome en un algoritmo dentro de un Onsuccess de un Page Method

Tags: vb.net, google-maps, google-chrome

Estoy haciendo una web app con vb.net programando en javascript y haciendo marker personalizados en google map api con javascript.
En windows explorer, edge dibuja bien los markers, que son tomados de un path, del servidor web donde está corriendo.
En chrome no los dibuja. Traspaso parte del còdigo, espero puedan ayudarme. Gracias

```
 /*clase para hacer dibujo icon que se pueda rotar y poner en un marker 13-   12-2016*/
var RotateIcon = function (options) {
    this.options = options || {};
    this.rImg = options.img || new Image();
    this.rImg.src = this.rImg.src || this.options.url || '';
    this.options.width = this.options.width || this.rImg.width || 52;
    this.options.height = this.options.height || this.rImg.height || 60;
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = this.options.width;
    canvas.height = this.options.height;
    this.context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.canvas = canvas;
};

RotateIcon.makeIcon = function (url) {
    return new RotateIcon({ url: url });
};

RotateIcon.prototype.setRotation = function (options) {
    var canvas = this.context,
        angle = (options.deg ) ? (options.deg) * Math.PI / 180 : options.rad,
        centerX = this.options.width / 2,
        centerY = this.options.height / 2;

    canvas.clearRect(0, 0, this.options.width, this.options.height);
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(centerX, centerY);
    canvas.rotate(angle);
    canvas.translate(-centerX, -centerY);
    canvas.drawImage(this.rImg, 0, 0);
    canvas.restore();
    return this;
};

RotateIcon.prototype.getUrl = function () {
    return this.canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
};

var image = {
    url: RotateIcon.makeIcon(localdat.pathdibu)
                   .setRotation({ deg: corregirrotacion(this.rotacion) })
                   .getUrl(),
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(52, 60) 
  }

this.pointHito = new google.maps.Marker({
    icon: image,
    optimized: false,
    position: flightPlanCoordinates[0],
    map: map


     // scaled size
```

Comment: aclaro que el marker se genera en una onsuccess funcion resultado de un llamado a una funcion page method

Comment: Creo que el dato de que haya vb.net en el backend es un poco irrelevante. Te pediría si puedes revisar el contenido de `image`. Por ejemplo creando un elemento `<img>` y asignándole `image.url` como atributo `src`. Con eso se puede comprobar que no es problema del marker ni de google maps sino de la generación de la imagen